# AzureBlobCredentialMissing Error only occurs when triggered, versus no error in Debug

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I get the following error in a pipeline that's first activity is to do a lookup on a storage container to get the contents of a file.   When I test the connectionns, linked server, datasets or debug the pipeline I do not receive any errors.  However when the pipeline is triggered by the storage event, it throws this error:

> ErrorCode=AzureBlobCredentialMissing,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Please provide either connectionString or sasUri or serviceEndpoint to connect to Blob.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

[image]

Comment: @BhanunagasaiVamsi That is the complete error message.  I updated my post to include a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0):

As per your scenario, where the debug is successful but the trigger runs failing. This make me assume that your dev changes have not been published which is why the trigger run fails. In simple terms the most recent published version of your linked service is different than that of your development version which haven't been published.

In case if you are using Source control then I would recommed following this tutorial for best practices - [Automated publishing for continuous integration and delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements)

If you are using CI-CD, then the issue might indeed cause by the DevOps pipeline not overriding the linked service parameters. Try redeploying the resource bye following below step and it should work as expected. (Linked service parameters had to be overwritten on the Azure resource template)

For example, if you have a linked service such as below:

[image]

Then you will still have to add below values into the overrideParameters section of the AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment task.

[image]